# Express redirect to front-end route with path

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I have a SPA that has a route /contact

For the direct requests to Express (ie. not to index.html) I need to execute a redirect.

In Express I can define this route like this:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
    if (req.path === "/contact" ) {
        return res.redirect("/?path=" + req.path);
    }
    next();
});
```

This means that if the user makes a direct request they will end up on index.html with "domain.com/?path=contact" in their address bar. Then the front-end can take care of the routing etc.

But maybe there is a way to do this so the user does not see this ugly url?

***EDIT: Is it an acceptable practice to include this path info in the HTTP headers sent to the user?***

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in sending the index.html file as a response. That way the address bar never changes.

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
    if (req.path === "/contact" ) {
        res.sendFile(...);
        return;
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: Yes, this solution is acceptable, and not the one in the question. Although, you may want to use a template engine ( express-hbs) to simplify things. Then you can just call ``` res->render('<template>.html, data); ```